# Enviar ArrayList de Strings via UDP em java

Tags: java

Ola, a questão é a seguinte:
Como envio um ArrayList todo via UDP do Servidor para o cliente em Java?
Conseigo enviar uma String somente por vez e funciona muito bem. Porem não sei como enviar um ArrayList de Strings.

Parte do meu codigo

SERVIDOR

```
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    request.setData("Testando".getData());
    DatagramPacket reply = 
    new DatagramPacket(request.getData(), request.getLength(), request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
    aSocket.send(reply);
```

CLIENTE

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            aSocket.receive(reply);
            System.out.println("Resposta:" + new String(reply.getData()));
```

Dessa maneira consigo enviar a palavra "Testando" do servidor parao cliente. Porem queri Enviar um ArrayList de Strings!

Comment: Pq você precisa enviar via UDP? Acho que só complica as coisas, comparado com o TCP. Os pacotes vão chegar em ordem diferente, por exemplo.

Comment: De qualquer forma, para enviar objetos você precisa usar o ObjectOutputStream e gravar em um buffer (use ByteArrayOutputStream e toByteArray()).